# Canvas image become distorted after slice and shrink in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mobile-safari

I try to load some big sprite images (1998x800), then slice it to single image and draw the image on Canvas, and try to switch these images by mouse or button action.

But I found when I shrink image and switch to the other image, the image will become distorted in iOS Safari. I try the sample on iPad1(iOS 5.1.1) and iPhone4(iOS 6.1), the problem both occurs.

Is it the bug of Mobile Safari? Is any solution?

Draw method:

```
    cont.drawImage(currentImg, 0, 0, 666, 800, 0, 0, drawWidth, drawHeight);
```

Sample Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/v5uuL/

Step:
1. Click 'Smaller' button to shrink image.
2. Click 'Part 2' button to draw second sprite image on canvas.
3. Th image which is drawn on canvas become distorted.

Note that:
* The size of sprite image is 1998 * 800, and each sprite image includes three images.So the size of those single image in sprite image is 666 * 800.
* If you click 'Bigger' button, then click 'Smaller' button, the problem will not happen.

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC1W5.png (normal)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y79D3.png (distorted - the second sprite image)

Comment: What do you mean by distorted (can you provide a snapshot)? The image seem to be fine here - it's from a little different angle as in the original image... have you compared in other browsers? (FF, Chrome..)

Comment: Desktop browser shows well, the problem only happens on iOS Safari.

Comment: See if this modification helps: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/v5uuL/1/ (I cannot test in iOs). Besides from your loader mechanism, the code seem to be fine. I modified the loader to eliminate any potential problems with the setInterval that you implemented. If still no success you are probably dealing with a bug.

Comment: Thanks. But problem still happens. I think it may be the bug of Mobile Safari Canvas render engine...